# Android content Uri cannot be played by other app

Tags: android, android-intent, storage, fileprovider

I used download manager to download a file to external storage.
I set the destination to Download folder using

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)
```

After success I retrieve the uri with

```
val fileUri=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))
```

which gives me this

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/dishapatani_Jan%2007%2C%2008%3A07_1609986166669.mp4
```

Now I try to play this video file using intent with this

```
  val uri=Uri.parse(" file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/dishapatani_Jan%2007%2C%2008%3A07_1609986166669.mp4")
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), requireContext().packageName + ".provider", File(localUri))

        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "video/mp4")
        intent.setData(contentUri)
        startActivity(intent)
```

Here content Uri is `content://com.myapp.provider/external_path/dishapatani_Jan%252007%252C%252008%253A07_1609986166669.mp4`

But it neither does played not it is recognized by other app when I use action_share intent.

Also the file uri that has file:// has to be removed  and replaced with
/storage/emulated/0/Download/dishapatani_Jan%2007%2C%2008%3A07_1609986166669.mp4"
else app crashes saying no root configured.

Here is my provider path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_path" path="/Download" />
</paths>
```

and manifeast

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

Comment: `After success I retrieve the uri with` Where does that cursor come from? Code does not look ok.

Comment: Cursor comes from download manager. Code is okay

Answer (score 0):

Dont mess around with paths and uries and your own file provider.

You got -or can get- an uri from the downloadmanager.

Use that to play the file.

Comment: Playing is okay. But for share I need the content uri.

Comment: Why? I see no need for that. And what you get from the download manager is a content uri too.