# Permission denied while sharing content uri from intent via fileprovider

Tags: android, android-intent, fileprovider

I have downloaded data from download manager, taken its local uri and convered to content uri getting this `content://com.myapp.name.provider/external_path/seedsheet-Jan-07-22-31_1610037996323.mp4`

How ever when I try to open it via intent

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        val localUri = downloadItem.localUri.replace("file://", "")
        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), requireContext().packageName + ".provider", File(localUri))
    intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, fileHelper.getMimeType(requireContext(), contentUri))
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
    startActivity(intent)
```

I can play file on android R but when I try to play on android Q I get "File cannot be played"
via MX player. Also when I try for the images, even image does not open. When I open log cat, it was written that permission is denied and file not found.

Comment: No. You are not telling what you do and you already asked this before but ran away: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606320/android-content-uri-cannot-be-played-by-other-app

Comment: And you are not telling that your file provider tries to serve a file from Download folder which is not possible on Q but on Android 11 it is.

Comment: As said before: use the uri you can get from the download manager. Don't mess around with paths and providers. And you do not need any permission.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I get content uri from download manager?

Comment: Well you obtained a cursor. For that you had to use that uri. Post complete code there.

Answer (score 0):

Your app has appropriate permissions to access the file system?

Comment: yes it does have read and write permissions to storage. On android R when I share the file, it is detected by facebook, instagram, gallery, etc and plays smoothly but when I use it on android Q, no app can read the media. Every app almost says cannot read this kind of file.